# How to retrieve VideoMediaType from a MediaType in MediaFoundation with SharpDX

Tags: c#, ms-media-foundation, sharpdx

I'm trying to capture video from a WebCam using SharpDX.MediaFoundation (4.2.0). I'm able to render the default media type, but I want to be able to select between the different available formats of the device.

I can enumerate the device sources but I'm unable to get information about the video media types.

```
var attributes = new MediaAttributes(1);
attributes.Set(CaptureDeviceAttributeKeys.SourceType.Guid, CaptureDeviceAttributeKeys.SourceTypeVideoCapture.Guid);

var mediaSource = MediaFactory.EnumDeviceSources(attributes)[0].ActivateObject<MediaSource>();
mediaSource.CreatePresentationDescriptor(out var presentationDescriptor);

for (int d = 0; d < presentationDescriptor.StreamDescriptorCount; d++)
{
    presentationDescriptor.GetStreamDescriptorByIndex(d, out var isSelected, out var streamDescriptor);
    for (int i = 0; i < streamDescriptor.MediaTypeHandler.MediaTypeCount; i++)
    {
        var type = streamDescriptor.MediaTypeHandler.GetMediaTypeByIndex(i);
        if (type.MajorType == MediaTypeGuids.Video)
        {
            var v = type.QueryInterface<VideoMediaType>();
            // contains always empty values
            var x = v.VideoFormat;
        }
    }
}
```

QueryInterface was not working. so I tried

```
new VideoMediaType(type.NativePointer)
```

But the result is the same.

Additionally I tried the same with a SourceReader

```
 var reader = new SourceReader(mediaSource);
 var mediaTypeIndex = 0;

 using (var mt = reader.GetNativeMediaType(0, mediaTypeIndex))
 {
     if (mt.MajorType == MediaTypeGuids.Video)
     {
         //var vmt = new VideoMediaType(mt.NativePointer);
         var v = mt.QueryInterface<VideoMediaType>();
         var x = v.VideoFormat;
     }
 }
```

Same result. Any advises?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to capture from your webcam? Do you have sample code?

Comment: @NickeManarin No, but I've switched to the UWP API's from Windows.Media.Capture to do the capturing.

Comment: Thanks, I think that I'm going to switch to that too, since I'm getting issues with the capture image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61830428/how-to-capture-frames-from-a-webcam-with-sharpdx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should cast to `SharpDX` `MediaType` instead as it corresponds to [IMFMediaType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfobjects/nn-mfobjects-imfmediatype), but you already have it in mt variable anyway. It's `IMFMediaType` that describes the video and audio media types provided by sources. `VideoMediaType` or `IMFVideoMediaType` is not guaranteed to be available.

You should be able to access different properties of the video media type contained in `mt` by using it like this:

```
using (var mt = reader.GetNativeMediaType(0, mediaTypeIndex))
{
    UnpackLong(mt.Get(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.FrameSize), out var width, out var height);
}

//Gets two integers from a long.
private void UnpackLong(long value, out int left, out int right)
{
    left = (int)(value >> 32);
    right = (int)(value & 0xffffffffL);
}
```

Check the `SharpDX` interfaces [here](http://sharpdx.org/wiki/class-library-api/mediafoundation/#api-Interfaces) (search for `IMFMediaType`).